# Batman.js model encoding issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, batman.js

I'm running into an interesting issue with a complex model association.

I have a Project, which has many Tasks, as well as a sole Task that it derives it's own information from. (Tasks can be converted to Projects to embed additional Tasks underneath them)

```
class Settr.Project extends Batman.Model
  @resourceName: 'projects'
  @storageKey: 'projects'

  @persist Batman.RailsStorage, serializeAsForm: false

  @belongsTo 'owner', name: 'User', inverseOf: 'projects'
  @belongsTo 'task',  inverseOf: 'project'
  @hasMany 'tasks'


  @encode 'task_id', 'owner_id'
  @encodeTimestamps()
```

The task Model may belong to a project's hasMany relationship, or it may play a hasOne relationship if it is the inverse of the 'task' property.

```
class Settr.Task extends Batman.Model
  @resourceName: 'tasks'
  @storageKey: 'tasks'

  @persist Batman.RailsStorage, serializeAsForm: false

  @belongsTo 'user'
  @belongsTo 'project', inverseOf: 'task', saveInLine: true
  @hasOne 'project'
  @hasMany 'entries', name: 'TaskEntry', inverseOf: 'task', saveInline: true

  @accessor 'lastEntry', ->
    @get('entries').reduce (a, b) ->
      (if a.created_at < b.created_at then a else b)

  @encode 'user_id', 'project_id'
  @encodeTimestamps()
```

In the future I will me implementing the ability to have Tasks repeat and allow for a history of a given's Tasks occurances to be viewed. This model is represented by TaskEntry

```
class Settr.TaskEntry extends Batman.Model
  @resourceName: 'entries'
  @storageKey: 'entries'

  @persist Batman.RailsStorage

  @PRIVACY_OPTIONS = ['is_public', 'is_private', 'is_follower']
  @DIFFICULTY_OPTIONS = ['','easy', 'moderate', 'hard']
  @STATUS_OPTIONS = ['incomplete', 'complete']

  @belongsTo 'task', inverseOf: 'entries'
  @urlNestsUnder 'task'
```

Now the issue. When I want to post a new Project, I have to embed a new Task for the Project, and give that Task a TaskEntry and set its title property. (Title is the only required field)

What is interesting is when my project is formatted like this: (same as above)

```
class Settr.Project extends Batman.Model
  @resourceName: 'projects'
  @storageKey: 'projects'

  @persist Batman.RailsStorage, serializeAsForm: false

  @belongsTo 'owner', name: 'User', inverseOf: 'projects'
  @belongsTo 'task',  inverseOf: 'project'
  @hasMany 'tasks'

  @encode 'task_id', 'owner_id'
  @encodeTimestamps()
```

I am able to retrieve Projects, but not post a new project.

If I encode the 'task' in the Project model, I am then able to post successfully, but am no longer able to retrieve. Example below.

```
class Settr.Project extends Batman.Model
  @resourceName: 'projects'
  @storageKey: 'projects'

  @persist Batman.RailsStorage, serializeAsForm: false

  @belongsTo 'owner', name: 'User', inverseOf: 'projects'
  @belongsTo 'task',  inverseOf: 'project'
  @hasMany 'tasks'

  @encode 'task_id', 'owner_id', 'task'
  @encodeTimestamps()
```

From the [Batman.js API Docs on @encode](http://batmanjs.org/docs/api/batman.model.html#class_function_encode), I have found that @encode can be customized like so.

```
@encode 'myProperty',
  decode: (value, key, incomingJSON, outgoingObject, record) -> # returns a value to set on the record
  encode: (value, key, builtJSON, record) ->                    # returns a value to put into the JSON
  as: "my_property"                                             # overrides "myProperty" as the JSON key
```

But I'm not quite sure if this is the right solution for me, or if my issue is somewhere else. If this is the solution I want, how do I use it appropriately? The documentation is a little bit over my head.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be caused by this naming conflict:

```
@belongsTo 'project', inverseOf: 'task', saveInLine: true
@hasOne 'project'
```

That defines two accessors for `project` -- I think the later one overrides the earlier one.

You could rename the `hasOne` association without changing the JSON API:

```
@hasOne 'special_project', foreignKey: 'project_id'
```

(you must provide `foreignKey`, otherwise it would default to `special_project_id`)